# XMLHttpRequest is not being made from FIrefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to communicate currently playing YouTube data with a node.js Express server via a Firefox extension. The extension loads correctly. However, the request simply isn't made. As in, the function to send the request just isn't called. I made sure that code execution continues before and after the function is called. Here is the code I wrote to send the video title to the main server.

```js
const hostname = "localhost:3621";

console.log("Plugin Started");

function sendTitle(title) {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = `http://${hostname}/?song=${title}`;

    console.log(url);

    request.open("GET", url);
    request.send(null);

    console.log("Request sent");
    console.log(request.url);
}
```

This `sendTitle()` function is called periodically by another function, that retrieves the name from the web page. This function is called using the `setInterval()` function, and is called every 5000ms

```js
function getVideoTitle() {
    // Get the current video title by reading page elements
    // This will be used to report the video information back to the server

    var pageItems = document.getElementsByClassName("ytd-video-primary-info-renderer");
    var titleObject = pageItems[6];

    console.log(titleObject.innerHTML);

    sendTitle(encodeURIComponent(titleObject.innerHTML));
}
```

I have verified that both of these functions are being called.

One other thing I tried was running the code I wrote in the `sendTitle()` function directly from the console. This worked and the request was sent. I also enabled `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on the node.js Express server as this was causing issues.

I have no idea why Firefox seems to simply skip over the `request.send()` part. No errors are reported, and code execution continues as normal.

I can also open the URL that the script produces in another tab and the request is sent fine. I have verified that this is not a problem with the server or the code I have written. I'm assuming this has something to do with Firefox's privacy configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that the request was not denied by tracking protection.
You could click this shield icon as next pic after you try to send a ajax request.

[image]

Then you could see if this request has been blocked by Firefox. If so please close this block and try again.

Comment: This does not seem to fix the issue. [I turned off the tracking protection](https://i.imgur.com/4pcgwAq.png) and noticed no change. I also looked at the XHR logs in the console, [nothing was sent](https://i.imgur.com/6qBK64b.png)

Comment: Maybe you could open the console( pressing F12) , then change the tab 'Network', then try it again and monitor if any xhr ajax request sent from browser

Comment: I just tried this. No luck. I tried filtering for localhost. I also tried changing the address in the code from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`. Still no luck. I've been browsing the internet and I found out about the "cross-domain-content" permission but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: I saw you use sendTitle called in getVideoTitle, maybe you should check again if there is any error in the calling flow.

Comment: If you could execute the function normally in console, it should also worked in js code

Comment: I could not get this to work either. I tried using `var xrh = new Request("http://localhost:3621/?song=whatever", { method: "GET" })` and then running `fetch(xrh)` but still no luck. I got so fed up that I even re-wrote the entire thing from scratch. No idea why this is not working